Is PMI as a Peano Axiom circular?
In Tao's Analysis, he defines the principle of mathematical induction as follows:

Axiom 2.5 (Principle of mathematical induction). Let $P(n)$ be
any property pertaining to a natural number $n$. Suppose that $P(0)$
is true, and suppose that whenever $P(n)$ is true, $P(S(n))$ is also
true. Then $P(n)$is true for every natural number $n$.

Then he goes on to say that $\mathbb{N}$ is defined to be the number system that adheres to the Peano Axioms. But my question is, since a natural number is an element of $\mathbb{N}$ how can we refer to them in the axioms if we have not yet defined $\mathbb{N}$? This seems rather circular, as if we are using the natural numbers to define the natural numbers.

Tao can be pretty handwavy around issues like this. In the given axiom, you can read "natural number" as "object". That is, the axiom doesn't care which number system it is "about". See domain of discourse.

As per previous comment, it is a question of clarity of exposition.
Compare the exposition of arithmetic -following Peano's axioms- into E.Landau's Foundations.
See page 1:

We assume the following to be given: A set (i.e. a totality) of objects called natural numbers, possessing the properties -called axioms- to be listed below.

The usual Peano's axioms follows, up to (page 2):

Axiom 5 (Axiom of Induction): Let there be a set $\mathfrak M$ of natural numbers, with the following properties [...] Then $\mathfrak M$ contains all the natural numbers.

There is no circularity, but the (explicit) assumption that there is a domain of objects from which we "carve out" the collection -usually denote $\mathbb N$- of natural numbers being the collection of all and only those objects satisfying all the specific axioms.
